# AWS CLoud Formation Templates, how to populate description dynamic

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to show the pricing for EC2 instance as a description simply a Tag, I have created a mapping for each instance type and price. But i want to show the price price while creating the stack just on parameter section. I am updating the default value as-

```
"Price": {
  "Description": "Price per hr for the EC2 instances",
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "Pricing" , { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },"Price"]}"
}
```

but it is not working , as the Default Value takes String.

Is there any other approach ?

Comment: This question isn't clear to me. What type of resource are you trying to create?

Comment: EC2 instance, but trying to display instance price per hr while creating.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible, here is what i found from the AWS docs

> The value for the description declaration must be a literal string that is between 0 and 1024 bytes in length. You cannot use a parameter or function to specify the description

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-description-structure.html

Comment: i got that but it says - "You cannot use a parameter or function to specify the description" . I tried this with my approach , but no luck :(

Comment: It has to be a string , I tried your way and also `Fn::sub`

Comment: why dont you programatically change the cloudformation json to modify the description and call stack creation ?

Comment: We can do that, but it is just we need for a catalog purpose. Can you suggest any alternative approach ? In Mapping section , based on instance type i have define the Price. i need to just masrk it as a description below where we are choosing instance type.

Comment: Why don't you add a tag

Comment: Actually adding tag is a good idea, but i need to display on the stac k - --

Comment: I'd just export an `Output` with the price you've calculated. Ok, the user will have to check `Outputs`, but at least the value will be visible.